# Egg Yolk Sub for Vegan Potato Gnocchi

Tags: substitutions, eggs, pasta, vegan

Attempts at potato gnocchi Piedmont style -no egg- has yielded rubber bullets or baby mush.

Tips from this site may help (ie old potato,freshly baked and riced) with a vegan version but their recommended egg yolk recipe has me hoping for a breakthrough:
Would other egg pasta substitutes have the desired effect of producing resilient pillows?

EVOO or Aquafaba show up in a few 'egg' noodle recipes; would that help? Or perhaps a potato protein based whole-egg replacer like Panaceg?

https://www.countrytrading.co/blogs/home-cooking/tips-to-make-perfect-potato-gnocchi

Comment: Have you searched for vegan gnocchi recipes? I appreciate that it's interesting figuring out your own substitution but your research will go much faster if you compare it to what others have done too.

Comment: I would go with a vegan gnocchi recipe, honestly - no need to reinvent the wheel. The one I use is not in English, but I can send you a link if you want

Comment: Yes, done the stated vegan Piedmont style for years. The binding gluten-softening power of a yolk is well substituted for in 'egg noodle'; why not extend the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer egg-yolk gnocchi but I’ve been successful in making yolk-free, pillowy, fluffy gnocchi by subbing out a couple of the russets (~1/5 the total weight of the potatoes) with yams or sweet potatoes in combination with my own invention that my spouse calls it “yuck yolk” because it looks like pet vomit. It's a combo of finely ground flax or ground chia seed soaked in a little aquafaba. The high Omega 3 content of flax can impart a fishy flavor so don’t overdo it.

The resulting gray mush should have a pudding-like texture. I lay riced potatoes on a cookie sheet as soon as they’re baked to let the steam out of them.

Then I sprinkle a small amount of the pudding-like ground seed/aquafaba mush over the potatoes and work it in with my fingers until it’s well distributed. I use about the same volume I would if I were using yolks (meaning, if I were using 1 yolk/lb potatoes, I’d use a seed/aquafaba pudding volume equivalent of 1 actual yolk).

Finally, I work in the flour until it feels right (holds together well enough to be rolled into the dough snakes from which the gnocchi is cut).

I’m afraid I can’t provide measurement guidance as I cook by feel, smell, taste, and never measure anything (unless I’m baking). I vary my recipe depending on intended use.

For example, if I want an ultra fluffy gnocchi for a light dish, I’ll use old dry potatoes and very little flour. If, on the other hand, I want to bake uncooked gnocchi in a sauce, I’ll increase the flour so that they hold together during a long submerged baking (this is a great thing to try with larger gnocchi baked in a marinara sauce).

Anyway, just have fun. Gnocchi is very forgiving. You can just make small batches and play around with proportions and egg substitutes until you nail it down.

Answer (score 0):

Several online recipes call for adding [olive oil to the dough](https://www.thecuriouschickpea.com/homemade-vegan-gnocchi-recipe/) to soften it.  Is this something you've tried?

Comment: Yes in 'Egg' Noodle not potato gnocchi and why I referenced EVOO  -extra virgin olive oil-

Comment: Found a couple recipes that add a teaspoon EVOO for a kilo potato so I imagine doesn't do much

Comment: The one I linked uses 2 Tbs.

Answer (score -1):

Unsweetened Applesauce will do the trick. 2 Tbsp for one egg.

Comment: please tell me more: have you actually done this with POTATO gnocchi or is this a substitute for muffins?

Comment: Assuming that your recipe includes some flour as well the applesauce binder should work. I would use both flour and applesauce so that they dont become too chewy. I have not done this but it is what i would try. There are also many vegan gnocchi recipes that show up with a google search.

Comment: I'll wait until you try it.

Comment: The recipe linked was vegan when doing Piedmont style. They recommended Veneto style by adding egg yolk. As stated.

Answer (score -2):

The juices in a can of chickpeas has enough plant protein in it that you can use it for a egg sub in a meringue. Try chickpea juices.

Comment: When you have dumped a can of aqua faba into riced potato and tried to make gnocchi, let us know.

Comment: Unless you are an actual teenager you can replace your thinly veiled sarcastic comment with an actuall critique.

Comment: Sorry to offend, Neil. I know aquafaba is super popular but it works only in a narrow spectrum of applications. Any fat, for example, deflates. It must be dried carefully to maintain structure. I was looking for the more gelling quality of yolk rather than white. Gnocchi were successful using piedmont technique: old potato baked riced, right amount of flour.

Comment: When making gnocchi it’s important to keep the moisture level as low as possible. This seems like it would result in soup, not gnocchi. Do you have experience with this?